# In-app purchase error of item is not avaliable in android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have problem with In-app purchase. I done all this for this with is required.

This is my code for open purchase intent.

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(), "test", RC_REQUEST1, purchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

In this code in-stand of test I try my all id but same problem with all. See in this pic

[image: This is error for in-app.]

Comment: please check product id you give in your code and product id at google side

Comment: did you publish the item on play console?

Comment: @santoXme... I done that there is test and all other.

Comment: @FarooqArshed... yes i publish it its in bita testing

Comment: I am not talking about your app. I am talking about your inapp product. did you publish it as well?

Comment: @FarooqArshed... yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check that "billing" permission is there in your manifest file or not!!

If you didn't give it then add this in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```